# Edit the comment(s) of an OP

Tags: support, comments, editing, suggested-edits

I ask to the more experts of TeX.SE if there is the possibility of editing the comments of users, without having to write or observe some errors of typography or code with another comment that could create or discomfort or embarrassment... similar to being able to edit regular posts, for example.

Comment: What exactly would you like to edit in OP's comments? I don't understand.

Comment: @Johannes_B For example sometimes I notice that there are writing errors (missing letters), some comment that reports extracts of code not complete. These are some examples.

Comment: A missing letter in a comment is nothing that needs to be fixed. Comments are just comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

> Users may edit their own comments any number of times for five minutes after they are first posted. Edited comments are marked with a little pencil icon, and a mouseover tooltip over that icon will provide a count of how many times the comment was edited, like this: [image: Pencil icon]
>
> Moderators can edit any comment at any time. Moderator comment edits are logged and visible to other moderators, but no revision history is kept. Such edits [will](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66387/168244) also show the pencil icon.
>
> In all other situations, comments cannot be edited. However, in lieu of editing, they may be deleted and resubmitted.

Reference: [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/168244)